# How to navigate IntelliJ dialogs using the underlined characters

Tags: dialog, navigation, intellij-idea

In IDEA (12) under Mac OS, how do I navigate the dialog windows using the underlined characters like it is know from Windows?

Take the Run/Debug Configuration dialog. Here all option-names have one of their characters underlined. In 'Name', N is underlined. How do I navigate to the 'Name' field with this (because merely pressing N with or without any of the usual modifiers does nothing)?

thanks /c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> is the generic mnemonic trigger).

Comment: Just replied the same question sent to JetBrains Support =)

Comment: damn you are right. I was sure I tried that as I was hammering away on the keyboard.  Thanks mate.